# memcache session error

Tags: magento-1.9, session, memcached, error-log

I used `memcached` for sessions, but I got error for `session_module_name`

error is :

```
Warning: session_module_name(): Cannot find named PHP session module (memcache)  in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 73
```

This is my local.xml

```
<session_save><![CDATA[memcache]]></session_save>
<session_save_path><![CDATA[tcp://127.0.0.1:11211?persistent=1&weight=2&timeout=10&retry_interval=10]]></session_save_path>
```

also this is my memcache result

```
[root@myserver]# ps ax | grep memcache
19669 ?        Ssl    0:37 memcached -d -p 11211 -u memcached -m 64 -c 5024 -P /var/run/memcached/memcached.pid -l 127.0.0.1
23788 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep memcache
```

and ports

```
[root@myserver]# netstat -tulpn | grep :11211
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      19669/memcached
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211             0.0.0.0:*                               19669/memcached
```

what is wrong here for memcached configuration?

I can login and logout without problem, also telnet work as well and `stats` show me every thing!

Comment: Do you use HHVM or usual php?

Comment: Server is configured manual by myself and everything installed one by one!

Comment: Have you checked if php memcache module is installed?
`php -m | grep memcache`

Comment: Yup, result is `memcache
memcached`

Comment: Console php and php cli can have different configuration. Could you put phpinfo() sumewhere? And check enabled modules.

Comment: Did you restart apache after installing memcached?

Comment: Used nginx, YES!

Comment: Are you using php5-fpm? If so restart that too. I know it may sound like a dumb thing to suggest but what you're describing sounds like something has not been restarted after installation.

Comment: I think this question may be off-topic because it is about server configuration.

Comment: This issue come from another extension, when I disabled it them memcached work as well

Comment: What I've done: Removed `tcp://`, renamed `memcache` into `memcached`. Now it works.